# I am stuck at formating the textbox in vb.net

Tags: vb.net

My this code was working perfect but since I added loop through all entries in database this is keep throughing error of format.. any help ?
[image: This is where i am getting error]

Comment: http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofanexception/

Comment: Sir I am new at programming I dont even know how to post a question that you can understand

Comment: Welkom to SO . Don't show images but code .I suggest you peruse the SO Tour section as it shows how SO works. The How do I ask a good question? may help. In addition, you may find the SO Asking section useful. 

https://stackoverflow.com/tour

Comment: Because you are trying to sum a decimal and string. Enclose the sum operation in brackets. `.Text = (decimal1 + decimal2).ToString()`

Comment: You're a member of this site for more than 2 years now. Please post your code and error message as text here so it is readable and accessible.

Comment: You should probably turn Option Strict On.  That will these type of case mis-match errors to you at design time

Comment: If you are using C and C++ tags on some of your questions you are not "new to programming".

Comment: The error is saying the the string value in `RemainingTextBox.Text` cannot be converted to a `Decimal`.

Answer (score 0):

The `Value` property of a `DateTimePicker` is a `DateTime`. No need to convert. The `Days` property of a `TimeSpan` is an `Intege`r. No need to convert.

Instead of coding empty `If` blocks, you can use the keyword `Not` to negate the value of the condition.

`TryParse` is very handy method. It not only returns True or False but if True will fill in the second parameter with the converted type. Your conversion will fail for any non valid characters in the text box which would include currency symbols and thousand separators. Decimal separators are fine

```
Private Sub Button3_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button3.Click
    Dim date1 As DateTime = DateTimePicker1.Value
    Dim date2 As DateTime = DateTimePicker2.Value
    Dim days As TimeSpan = date2.Subtract(date1)
    Dim Tdays = days.Days
    'Let's check the validity of the text boxes first
    Dim Remaining As Decimal
    Dim Fees As Decimal
    If Not Decimal.TryParse(RemainingTextBox.Text, Remaining) Then
        MessageBox.Show("Please enter a valid number in the RemainingTextBox")
        Exit Sub
    End If
    If Not Decimal.TryParse(FeesTextBox.Text, Fees) Then
        MessageBox.Show("Please enter a valid number in the FeesTextBox")
        Exit Sub
    End If
    'After validation
    If Tdays > 30 Then
        MessageBox.Show("Total days over")
        If IsIncrementedCheckBox.Checked = False Then
            If Not ReceivedTextBox.Text = "" Then
                RemainingTextBox.Text = (Remaining + Fees).ToString
            End If
            IsIncrementedCheckBox.Checked = True
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```